# Mono: WCF Service Timeout with basichttpBinding (Mono 2.10.8.1)

Tags: wcf, mono, wcf-client, basichttpbinding

I'm having WCF Client with basicHTTPBinding. That is working fine when running in Windows. but when running from Mono (Debian 2.10.8.1-5, Mono JIT compiler version 2.10.8.1) I immmediately get a timeout.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.TimeoutException: The operation has timed-out.
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestChannel+HttpChannelRequestAsyncResult.WaitEnd () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestChannel.EndRequest (IAsyncResult result) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestChannel.Request (System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message message, TimeSpan timeout) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.ServiceModel.MonoInternal.ClientRuntimeChannel.Request (System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message msg, TimeSpan timeout) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.ServiceModel.MonoInternal.ClientRuntimeChannel.Request (System.ServiceModel.Description.OperationDescription od, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.ServiceModel.MonoInternal.ClientRuntimeChannel.DoProcess (System.Reflection.MethodBase method, System.String operationName, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.ServiceModel.MonoInternal.ClientRuntimeChannel.Process (System.Reflection.MethodBase method, System.String operationName, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TimeoutException: The operation has timed-out.
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestChannel+HttpChannelRequestAsyncResult.WaitEnd () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestChannel.EndRequest (IAsyncResult result) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestChannel.Request (System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message message, TimeSpan timeout) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.ServiceModel.MonoInternal.ClientRuntimeChannel.Request (System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message msg, TimeSpan timeout) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.ServiceModel.MonoInternal.ClientRuntimeChannel.Request (System.ServiceModel.Description.OperationDescription od, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.ServiceModel.MonoInternal.ClientRuntimeChannel.DoProcess (System.Reflection.MethodBase method, System.String operationName, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.ServiceModel.MonoInternal.ClientRuntimeChannel.Process (System.Reflection.MethodBase method, System.String operationName, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I already checked it is no network connection issue as it runs from other (windows based) clients. Also the application is not waiting for the set timeout of 1 minute.

Here is the code I'm using to call the service:

```
// Application Authentication
DiscoveryService.LDEDiscoveryServiceClient client = new DiscoveryService.LDEDiscoveryServiceClient();
client.InnerChannel.OperationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
Console.WriteLine("Connecting to: " + client.Endpoint.Address.Uri);
string token = client.GetTokenV1();
Console.WriteLine(token);
```

And the app.config for the binding configuration:

```
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ILDEDiscoveryService" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:01:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"/>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ILDEDeviceService" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:01:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"/>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://hostname/LDE/DiscoveryService/LDEDiscoveryService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ILDEDiscoveryService" contract="DiscoveryService.ILDEDiscoveryService" name="BasicHttpBinding_ILDEDiscoveryService"/>
            <endpoint address="http://hostname/LDE/DeviceService/LDEDeviceService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ILDEDeviceService" contract="DeviceService.ILDEDeviceService" name="BasicHttpBinding_ILDEDeviceService"/>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You might want to try the latest mono version to see if it's been fixed (many things have been fixed in this area since 2.10.8). If that fails, I suggest you file a bug: http://bugzilla.xamarin.com with a complete test case.

Comment: I thought 2.10.8 is the latest (stable) version. There is a 2.10.9 version but the release notes say that this is a Mac only Version. Or do you recommend to update to the mono 3.0 Version that is still a beta release (at least according to the download section of Mono-Project.com)

Comment: You should try the 3.0 version, it's still a beta, but it might still have fixed your issues.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to get mono 3.0 working currently. Unfortunately having some problems compiling it on my raspberry pi as `make` throws an error that ARM processors are not supported. But I'll continue trying and provide feedback if that one solved the issue or not as soon as mono 3.0 works for me.

Comment: Hi @Flo, any joy yet? I am having the same issue.

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same issue, using the Mono version within Unity 3d engine as the client, and IIS express as the service.

Comment: Nothing new so far. The ArmHardFloat fix for mono 3.0 is still missing: https://wiki.debian.org/ArmHardFloatTodo

Comment: This is also broken on Xamarin iOS 8.4.0.38.